# AWS site slow only from US

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, web-applications, tornado, amazon-elb

I have deployed a Tornado web app on AWS in Sydney, Australia. Most of my users are in Australia, but a few are in the US. The US users have reported that the site is very slow in their afternoon, which is around the start of the working day here. The site is definitely used more during the day in Australia, and yet no Australian users have reported any slowness. Here is a graph of average page views per hour:

[image: Page views by the hour]

When it's bad in the US, a computationally-expensive `PUT` request reportedly takes 45 seconds to complete, while here it takes less than one second. Not much data should be transmitted for this particular request. Cloud Watch shows a maximum [ELB latency](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-latency-troubleshooting/#3._Check_the_CloudWatch_Latency_metric)* of 15 seconds - unfortunately it doesn't show exactly which request that is, and it might be one of the detailed reports. Cloud Watch shows no correlation between queue length and latency: I tried adding a few extra servers, which reduced the queue length to zero, but the latency persists.

Is there some reason why accessing the site in the afternoon in the US would be slow? I know this is a fairly vague question, but I thought I'd see if there was anything obvious before I spend lots of time instrumenting the site to gather more data.

* *Latency* here is in the [ELB sense](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-latency-troubleshooting/#3._Check_the_CloudWatch_Latency_metric), i.e. the time it takes a back-end server to fully respond to a request.

Comment: Sounds like maybe slow requests are blocking the IOLoop somehow, and the extra latency of US traffic is making it worse?

Comment: Before you instrument the site, review the ELB logs. (!) Identify these reportedly slow requests, compare the logged response times to the reported response times.  Spin up a t2.nano instance in one of the 3 US regions and launch test requests from it against your site. My own preference is to run global sites through CloudFront, even when caching is not needed, since this can do some pretty dramatic things for performance by terminating the initial connection closer to the client and routing the traffic over the managed paths that make up the AWS edge network, avoiding some Internet vagaries.

Comment: @Michael Ah! I kind of thought AWS did closest-edge routing automatically. So I need CloudFront for that? Also I didn't realise there were ELB logs. I'll check that out.